# Clear VRAM on Linux

Tags: linux, gpu, xorg, vram

On some (or even a lot of) GPUs contents of video memory aren't cleared after it is resleased by an application. Contents of VRAM might even remain after reboot. Because of this, there's a risk of exposing sensitive information.

Is there a sure way to clear the contents of VRAM on Linux?

Comment: Somebody please help. How do we clear VRAM!